# Solving Probability Density Function for continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability density of a random variable $x$ is $$f(x)=a\ \cdotp x^2\ \cdotp \mathrm{e}^{−kx}\ (k>0,\ 0\leq x\leq \infty)$$ Then, the coefficient $a$ equals
$$(i)\frac{k^3}{2}\ \ \ \ (ii)\ k^3 \ \ \ \ (iii)\ k^2 \ \ \ \ (iv)\ k \ \ \ \ (v) \frac{2\ \cdotp k}{\pi}$$

> Here is what I've tried:
>
> $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x = 1$$ $$\int_0^\infty\left(a\ \cdotp x^2\ \cdotp \mathrm{e}^{−kx}\right)\mathrm{d}x = 1$$
>
> solving by parts gives result as
>
> $$\left[-\frac{a\cdotp\mathrm{e}^{-kx}}{k}\cdotp\left(x^2+\frac{2x}{k}+\frac{2}{k^2}\right)\right]^\infty_0 = 1$$
>
> Now, here I'm stuck. Can't find a way to solve $a$.

Comment: There should be no $x$ after evaluation of the integral. Complete your integration and then divide.

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. Evaluating the integration with one limit set to $\infty$. Don't know how to evaluate the LHS of the last equation.

Comment: Do you know that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\cdot e^{-kx} = \lim_{x\to\infty} x\cdot e^{-kx} = 0$? If not, can you prove it first? (Hint: L'Hopital's rule might need to be used).

Answer (score -1):

What you need instead is 
$$
a=\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 e^{-kx}dx}=\frac{k^3}{2}
$$

Comment: Could you please explain how have you arrived to $\frac{2}{k^3}$ from $\int_0^\infty x^2\mathrm{e}^{-kx}\mathrm{d}x$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with integration by parts? You need to apply it twice

Comment: Another possibility: $\int_0^{\infty}x^2 e^{-kx}dx = \frac{d^2}{dk^2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-kx} dx$